# Is there a limit on accessing dynamically allocated arrays through class functions in C++?

Tags: arrays, function, class, visual-c++

This is the start of a program I'm writing for a class I'm trying to get it to read a file that contains a number of floats. Using Doubles should not be a problem. I'm assuming that calling my function using array1.readDataFromFile();
will access the dynamically created array in the array1 structure? However when the

Here is the header file

```
// Specification file for the NuberArrayClass
//a.k.a NumberArrayClass.h file

#ifndef NUMBERARRAYCLASS_H
#define NUMBERARRAYCLASS_H

using namespace std;
// class declaration

class NumberArrayClass
{

private:
    int arraySize;
    double * numberArray = nullptr;

public:
    //constructor declaration
    NumberArrayClass();

    //member functions
    void readDataFromFile();
    void displayArray();

    //destructor
    ~NumberArrayClass()
    {
        delete[] numberArray;
    } // end of destructor


};
#endif // NUMBERARRAYCLASS_H
```

Here is the Class function file

```
//NumberArrayClass.cpp file

#include "NumberArrayClass.h" //needed to access arry
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //needed for file read

using namespace std;





NumberArrayClass::NumberArrayClass()
{
    arraySize = 250;  
    numberArray = new double[arraySize];
}



void NumberArrayClass::readDataFromFile()
{

    //creating a read object and opening file.
   ifstream inFile;

   inFile.open("DoubleData.txt");

   int countIt = 0; //this is a counter

   if (!inFile.fail())
   {
        cout << "File open!" << endl;
        //this should populate the
       while (countIt < arraySize && inFile >> numberArray[countIt]);
       {
            countIt++; //incramenting counter. 
       }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File Read fail!" << endl;
    }//end of if/else statement.



 }//end of readDataFromFile


void NumberArrayClass::displayArray()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
       cout << numberArray[i] << endl;
   }

 }//end of displayArray
```

Here is my main

```
//main .cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "NumberArrayClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //creating our class object.
    NumberArrayClass array1;

    array1.readDataFromFile();

    array1.displayArray();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure If I have the syntax wrong or what.. the file opens but array1.displayArray(); spits out garbage.

Comment: Check up there: `However when the.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line:

```
while (... && inFile >> numberArray[countIt]);
```

The `operator>>` doesn't return the success of the operation, [it returns the same `ifstream` it operates on](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) (so you can chain calls):

Split the condition and the assignment, and after the assignment check the [eofbit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/) to know if you reached the end of the file. There are also `badbit` and `failbit` you might want to look at.

About your title question `Is there a limit on accessing dynamically allocated arrays through class functions in C++?`: there is a practical limit, mandated by your SO and hardware, but if that's not what's happening here. If you were to encounter such problem, it would be in this line:

```
numberArray = new double[arraySize];
```

(Side-note, your destructor should be `virtual` in case you decide to derive from this class)

Comment: This is correct, looking at the problem I'm having is with my read not the array. Need to figure out how to read from a list of floats separated by '\n'. They are separated by white space but but my build only load the very last float into the first element of the array. I found this out by adding a initialization loop to the constructor for the array. I get the last float in the list and a bunch of zeros. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem here.
Suppose the number of floats/doubles is less than `arraySize`. This means that the while loop will terminate before `countIt` reaches `arraySize`.
However your display function loops through the whole `arraySize` elements of the array.
As the array was not initialized after allocation, this means that these elements contain garbage.

My suggestion is doing the following:

1. Initialize the array after allocation.
2. Only display a number of elements that was read by the read function.

Comment: #2 is correct, you should only display the data you know is valid. But I would suggest against #1 because it's unnecessary, there is nothing wrong with leaving uninitialized values in an array if you are not going to touch them (which means, do #2!).